# Sharing custom Angular formatting functions outside of template

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

If a custom Angular formatting/pipe function is needed outside of a template, what is the Angular way of sharing that function? Through a static export/import or through an [InjectionToken](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken#tree-shakeable-example)?

#### Option 1: Static export/import

```
export myFormatter(value: string): string {
  return ...
}
```

Use in service:

```
import { myFormatter } from 'my-formatter';

export class SomeService {
  ...
  const formattedValue = myFormatter(value);
  ... 
}
```

#### Option 2: InjectionToken

```
export const MY_FORMATTER = new InjectionToken('My Formatter', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => (value: string) => { return ... }),
});
```

Use in service:

```
import { MY_FORMATTER } from 'my-formatter';

export class SomeService {
  ...
  const myFormatter = this.injector.get(MY_FORMATTER);
  const formattedValue = myFormatter(value);
  ... 
}
```

My initial gut told me to use InjectionToken to leverage Angular's dependency injection system. On the other hand, [Angular exposes their formatting functions as of Angular 6 without the use of InjectionTokens](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/418091253887d45f38022fbf7db6dedad2857ac9#diff-28452bd574d6eaf07564aa07776d55ee). This raises the question, why does Angular not use DI for their own formatting function and how should we be sharing those functions?

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on Angular as it will use complex functions to share your code among different features.

Instead, consider relying on Typescript, by making an exportable function :

```
export function myFormatter(value: string): string {
  return ...
}
```

And in your features :

```
import { myFormatter } from 'path/to/file';

export class MyComponent {
  myFormatter = myFormatter;
}
```

You can also create a super class from that :

```
export class FormatterUtils {
  myFormatter(value: string): string {
    return ...
  }
}
```

And in your features

```
import { FormatterUtils } from 'path/to/file';

export class MyComponent extends FormatterUtils {
  constructor() { super(); }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on why you think it's okay to reply purely on TypeScript in this case? I would agree that DI is more complex as a whole but there are [reasons why we use DI](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#factory-providers). Why is it ok to forgo DI in this case? In response to your second suggestion, personally I disagree with the use of a super class for this case because `MyComponent` is not a `FormatterUtils` (it's not a `is-a` relationship). If I needed two formatters in `MyComponent` then that approach would not work since you can only inherit from one thing.

Comment: Two words : execution time. Once your files are bundled, exported functions are accessible on the spot. You have 1 instruction to get them. With DI, you have 10, 20, 1000 instructions to get a single function. This seems pretty obvious. And as for the second option, you didn't specify needing two formatters.

Comment: I agree with @SamHerrmann that the component should definitely not inherit from FormatterUtils - that is not a correct usage of inheritance. But other than that, I would agree that for simple re-usable 'pure functions' like this, straight typescript imports are a sensible choice. The overhead of DI is a worthwhile price to pay for complex services to keep your testing simple and confined - so it depends on how complex your formatting functions are and whether you would rather test them independently or in-place (if you do not inject them, you have to test them in place).